# Trying to update the value of a multidimensional associative array when I only know the location of a child element

Tags: php

I am running a recursive function for a multidimensional associative array. I know what I want to do but I can't figure out the right implementation. Let's say I have an array like this:

```
$my_array = array(
    '1' => array(
        'id' => '1',
        'parent' => false,
        'children' => array(
            '2' => array(
                'id' => '2',
                'parent' => '1',
                'children' => array(
                    '3' => array(
                        'id' => '3',
                        'parent' => '2',
                        'children' => array(
                            //how do I insert an array here if I only have only have the location '3' to work from?           
                        )    
                    )    
                )    
            )
       )
    )   
);
```

and I want to insert a new item array inside the child of item 3, but I only have 3 as the location. How do I get to a situation where I can do something like:

```
$my_array['1']['children']['2']['children']['3']['children'] = $my_array;
```

if I only have '3' as the location to work with and I don't know what the path will be before the '3'?

I thought about converting the array to json and then doing a search for 'id' => '3', and then trying to inject the array as json under the children section, but the problem with this is I couldn't figure out a way on how to find the closing bracket of the json because there could be other closing brackets inside existing children of item 3.

Comment: You could `foreach()` over the data and use a recursive function when you encounter an element with an element `children` - so pass the `children` back into the function till you find the id your after.

Comment: @NigelRen Perhaps, I was hoping there might be some easier solution because I already have a recursive function, so I am not super keen on having a recursive function doing another recursive function.