# How do I update the value in an associative array when the location/destination is represented as a string?

Tags: php, associative-array

If I have a string like:

```
$location_to_update = '3,2,1';
```

how can I convert this string into a location I need to update in an associative array i.e.

```
$my_array['3']['2']['1'] = 'my new value';
```

? So separate the commas (explode) and then turn that array into a variable that can update that part of an associate array? Thank you!

Comment: Does the string have a variable number of values?

Comment: Is this linked to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58038137/trying-to-update-the-value-of-a-multidimensional-associative-array-when-i-only-k) or something new?

Comment: @Nick yes, that's correct it will have a variable number of values

Comment: @NigelRen This is unrelated

Comment: Thanks @NigelRen for pointing out the duplicate I couldn't find this great answer!